# How to do a multidimensional array within a while loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

Im stuck with this simple problem in php:

```
$words = array();
while ($allrow = mysqli_fetch_array($all))
{       
    $words = "".utf8_encode($allrow["eng"])."" => "".$allrow["id"]."";                  
}

foreach ($words[] as $key => $word) {
```

I wanna have an array with some words and its id. In the foreach loop I need to be able to know which id each word has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You array building syntax is off, try this:

```
// array key is the id, swap if needed, but I assume the ids are unique
$words[$allrow["id"]] = utf8_encode($allrow["eng"]);
```

Every time you say `$words = $anything`, you are overwriting the last iteration.

This should have generated a parse error:

```
."" => "".
```

Not sure how that slipped by your testing. No need for the empty `""` strings either.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your foreach loop, add each entry to the array.

```
$words[utf8_encode($allrow["eng"])] = $allrow["id"];
```

if you actually want the id as the key, which is more probable, you reverse the assignment:

```
$words[$allrow["id"]] = utf8_encode($allrow["eng"]);
```

As well, you should not iterate using `$words[]`. That does not make sense. Use
`foreach($words as $key => $value)`

As assigning array values with `[]` and iterating arrays are basic concepts, you should study up on [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) before trying to use them.

Comment: I didn't even look at that last bit, this code is a mess. +1 for recommended reading on basic php.

Answer (score 0):

```
$words[$allrow["id"]] = utf8_encode($allrow["eng"]);
```

and then in the foreach loop use `foreach ($words as $key => $word) {`